# Probability of not picking a row in a random draw where the number of rows are N

Tags: probability, random-variable, combinatorics, discrete-distributions

**There are $N$ rows :$R_1, R_2,R_3,..., R_N$. What is the probability of not picking a row in a random draw?**

My try and understanding :

Let $X$ be a random variable which is defined as follows:
$$X = \text{ Number of rows picked in a random draw.}$$
So, the values of random variable which it can take are :
$$X = 0, 1,2,3,4,...N$$
Hence the required probability is :
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{ Probability of not picking a row in a random draw } & = 1-\text{Probability of picking a row in a random draw } \\
 & = 1 - P(X = 1) \\
 & = 1 - \frac{N}{2^N}
\end{aligned}
$$
The size of sample space is $|S| = 2^N$ and the favourable outcomes are $N$ for $X =1$

Could someone explain whats wrong in it, because I read a blog on the [medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-out-of-bag-oob-score-in-random-forest-a7fa23d710)* where it is mentioned the required probability is $\frac{N-1}{N}$. Follow the mentioned link or see the below screen shot:
[image]

**Note**: Please try to open the website in incognito mode to get rid from sign in etc and the probability thing is mentioned at the end of the blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is not explicitly mentioned in the article, so I think in this context, $X$ refers to the row number that is picked and **not** the number of rows picked in a random draw. If this is indeed the case, then I think the statement

> probability of not picking a row in a random draw is

should be re-worded to

> probability of not picking a row in a random draw of size $N = 1$

which would make it clearer. Since
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{N} p(X = i) &= 1 \\
\left[\sum_{i \neq x} p(X = i)\right] + p(X = x) &= 1 \\
\sum_{i \neq x} p(X = i) &= 1 - p(X = x) \\
&= p(X \neq x)
\end{align}
and so
$$
p(X \neq x) = \sum_{i \neq x} p(X = i)
$$
Since there are $N$ rows to pick from, and assuming that each row is equally likely to be picked, then
$$
\sum_{i \neq x} p(X = i) = \frac{N-1}{N}
$$

Comment: Thanks for rewording in a better and the used language sounds ambiguous to me , so i landed with different thought and answer.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, since medium articles are not peer-reviewed, you need to be wary of them. This is true for most articles on the internet.